# Why Firefox downloads heic files without extension?

Tags: firefox

I'm using Firefox (v102.0) on Ubuntu 20.04.

When I try to download a HEIC file (image format used by Apple), it always gets downloaded without the extension, so I have to rename it every single time.

Request and response are perfect:

[image]

This file however gets downloaded as `IMG_5248` (without extension).

My system is perfectly capable of showing heic files. But of course, if a file doesn't have an extension, the system has no idea of how to deal with it.

On the same machine, using Chrome works perfectly (downloading the same file).

How can I convince FF to respect *filename* in *Content-Disposition*?

FF doesn't have any specific setting for handling HEIC:

[image]

This is how the HTML part looks like:

[image]

And whenever I click on that `a`, this is the request:

[image]

Along with these headers:

[image]

Comment: Check your Firefox `Applications` settings to see if you're handling HEIC files in a special way somehow

Comment: My FF doesn't have any specifics for heic files.

Comment: What's the actual URL you're downloading (ie, can we see the request headers)-- it might be using that as the filename instead

Comment: Very silly question: are you looking at the file using `ls` or a file viewer that may be suppressing extensions?

Comment: It doesn't have extension, neither checking from command-line, nor from browsing the downloads folder with default navigator (Nautilus?). It's the same file (binary compared), but without the extension. IF I manually add the extension, my system *can* display it. Otherwise it just says unknown file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have to check whether the Issue is with your webserver or webbrowser or something else

(1) Check whether you can Download some HEIC files from here : https://filesamples.com/formats/heic

Is it getting saved with the correct extension ?

Check https://filesamples.com/formats/png and Download some PNG file to check whether that gets the correct extension

(2) In case those work correctly, try uploading some PNG (& DOC & txt) to your webserver and try to Download that. Does that get the correct extension ? Is it confirmed that only HEIC is having the Issue ?

(3) Try changing the file names on the webserver to eg (3A) lowercase, img5248.heic (3B) "multiple" extensions, img5248.check.heic, & img5248.heic.heic to check which "Part" is getting left out (3C) Deliberately "incorrect" extension, img5248.png

(4) Check with some other user & some other machine (maybe having some other OS) to make further eliminations.

**[[ When you get more Working Cases + more Non-Working Cases, the Issue will reveal itself. ]]**

All this, only when you get access to that machine & that webserver !

UPDATE:
By comparing "Working Case" with "Non-Working Case" , OP has seen the Difference in Content-Type :

Non-Working Case : Content-Type is image/heic
Working Case : Content-Type is application/octet-stream

Plausible Issue:  HEIC & HEIF have Patent Issues which make it hard to support in free software without licensing concerns. With given format, which firefox does not support fully, the extension is removed. When given "application/octet-stream", firefox simply saves it with given filename including "unknown" extension !

Comment: I am not at that computer now, but I can confirm that this is only related to heic files: all other type of files are saved correctly (png, jpg, PNG, JPG, bin, docx, pdf)

Comment: I want to add, to the Earlier list (4) Check with some other user & some other machine (maybe having some other OS) to make further eliminations. [[ When you get more working cases + more non-working cases, the Issue will reveal itself. ]] Ok, you should then move on to check whether it works on other webservers , like the given Example : https://filesamples.com/formats/heic ; then check with multiple extensions like the Example given : img5248.check.heic & then img5248.heic.heic to check which "Part" is getting left out ; All this, only when you get access to that machine & that webserver !

Comment: Sample files can be downloaded correctly. So it's something else, but whenever I start to download the problematic files (with heic extension), FF shows me that the file is actually a HEIF image. Is it meaning a problem?

Comment: Well, no, as for the samples it's the same. Checked with "img.check.heic" -> saving as "img.check". With "img.heic.check" -> saving as "img.heic.check". "img.jpg" -> "img.jpg", "img.png" -> "img.png".

Comment: The thing is that I have to add "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" to make this download work. If *Content-Type* is *image/heic*, it simply skips the extension.

Comment: When I try `curl -I https://filesamples.com/samples/image/heic/sample1.heic` , I get `content-type: application/octet-stream` **AND** Saving is working. I think we can safely conclude that this is the Issue. It has Patent Issues & thus firefox does not fully support it. When it is general a "octet-stream", firefox simply saves it with the given filename including "unknown" extension !

Comment: Yes, that's the reason I tried this solution. :) Thank you!